# Question concerning types, partial elementary maps and universality.

Tags: model-theory

Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $M$ realizes all $\lambda$-types of $M$ over $\emptyset$ for any $\lambda<\kappa$.
2. For any $N\equiv M$ and any $A \subseteq N$ with $|A|<\kappa$ there is a partial elementary map $f : N \to M$ with $A \subseteq dom(f)$.

Moreover, if $\kappa > |L|+\aleph_0$ then 1. and 2. are equivalent to:

3. $M$ is $\kappa$-universal.

Comment: I know what an $n$-type is. But what is a $\lambda$-type for infinite $\lambda$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'm having troubles from the begining, I can't even think of an strategy to approach.

Comment: @Stefan: is just as the regular finite concept extended to infinite. Consider a sequence of variables indexed in $\lambda < \kappa$ and extend the concepts

Comment: Well, there is more than one way to extend this concept. Are we allowed to use $\lambda$ many quantifiers/conjunctions/disjunctions in a formula? Do you know of a source where I can read about that?

Comment: @Stefan: Most of the classical books (e.g., Chang, Keisler; Tent, Ziegler, et al.) have an approach to it.

Comment: @Stefan Each formula in a $\lambda$-type is first order (and hence uses only finitely many variables). It's just that they use free variables from a supply $\{x_\alpha\mid \alpha < \lambda\}$. Here's an example: Given an infinite model $M$, enumerate $M = \{m_\alpha\mid \alpha < |M|\}$. Then the elementary diagram of $M$ (using variables $x_\alpha$ to represent the elements $m_\alpha$) is a $|M|$-type.

Comment: @Stefan Of course there are also notions of infinitary logic, where infinite boolean combinations and/or infinite blocks of quantifiers are allowed, and there are notions of type for these logics as well. But this question is about first-order logic.

Answer (score 2):

*Throughout, I write "type" for "type over $\emptyset$."*

The key piece of intuition, I think, should be the following: a "type" is just a *description*, of an object (or family of objects) which could exist. When I have a type $p$ with $\theta$-many variables, I think of that type as describing a collection of $\theta$-many elements, and telling me how they interact with each other (what relations hold and don't hold, etc.). The two key properties are *completeness* (which doesn't matter here so much) and *consistency* (which does - consistency means that the type is realized in some model, that is, there is some model with a bunch of things which are described by the type). Caution: just because something's *possible* doesn't mean it *happens* - I can write a type $p$ and have a model where nothing corresponding to $p$ occurs.

For example, the type $\{x>1+1+ . . . +1$ ($n$ times)$: n\in\omega\}$ is not realized in $(\mathbb{N}, <, +)$, but there are models of the theory of $(\mathbb{N}, <, +)$ in which it is realized, that is, models with some element $a$ which is $>1$, $>1+1$, $>1+1+1$, etc.

*OK fine that type's not complete but you know what I mean.*

Bottom line: think of "realizing a type" as "having a bunch of elements which look a certain way."

---

So with that in mind, here's a hint for (1) $\rightarrow$ (2): Fix $N\equiv M$ and $A\subseteq N$ with $\vert A\vert=\lambda<\kappa$. Now, by (1) we know that any $\lambda$-type $p$ is realized in $M$ by some elements $\overline{m}_p$; can you think of a type $p$ so that $A$ "looks like" $\overline{m}_p$? HINT: this type should describe $A$ in some way . . .

For (2)$\implies$(1), suppose I have a $\lambda$-type $p$. Being a type means $p$ is realized in some model . . . but maybe not $M$. (Of course, it will be, but we can't assume that - that's what we're trying to show.) So suppose $N$ is a model in which $p$ is realized, by some set $A$. Using (2), we can "transfer" $A$ to some tuple $B$ in $M$; what does this tuple have to do with $p$?

After you've worked these out, handling (3) should be easy.

Comment: this is erally helpful, I'll work on your insights, hopefully to accomplish the goals. Thanks a lot

Comment: I can see your point, and the way you suggest to treat the exercise: I know now that we have to use the elementary equivalence in order to go on; nevertheless, on direction $(1) \to (2)$ I'm having problems on describing the way the partial elementary map is build in order to hold the desired conditions.

Comment: Keep in mind $A$ is a *tuple*, and order matters: $A=\{a_\eta: \eta\in\lambda\}$. The type $p$ in the variables $x_\eta (\eta\in\lambda)$ is realized by $A$, in the sense that when we plug in $a_\eta$ for $x_\eta$ we get something which is true in $N$. Now look at $M$. The type $p$ is realized in $M$ by some tuple of elements $\overline{m}_p=\{m_\eta: \eta<\lambda\}$. Clearly $\overline{m}_p$ and $A$ "look alike"; is there any way to give an explicit map between them? That is, given some $a\in A$, which element of $\overline{m}_p$ should we send it to?

Comment: that's good, thanks, but the thing is that the partial elementary map must hold a condition over (any) formula, but the equivalence of $M$ and $N$ "speaks" only about sentences. I mean; we need to prove that there is $f : N \to M$ such that for every $\bar{a} \in dom(f)$ and for all $\varphi(\bar{x}) \in L$, $N \models \varphi(\bar{a})$ iff $M \models \varphi(f\bar{a})$ and that $A \subseteq dom(f)$; but $M \equiv N$ only says that they satisfy the same sentences

Comment: That's true, but it's not an issue. HINT: try to do this for $\lambda=1$ . . .